# что в js значит?

Tags: javascript

что в js значит `??` и чем он отличается от `||`?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/353446/

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/nullish-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это [оператор нулевого слияния](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

> Оператор нулевого слияния (??) это логический оператор, который
> возвращает значение правого операнда когда значение левого операнда
> равно null или undefined, в противном случае будет возвращено значение
> левого операнда.

Оператор `||` приступит ко второму операнду если первый будет любым ложным (`NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `''`, `false`).

А оператор `??` приступит ко второму операнду если первый будет `null` или `undefined`.

Comment: Спасибо большое.